# LINQ .FromCache().ToList()?

Tags: c#, linq, caching, ienumerable, ilist

When using `.FromCache()` on an `IQueryable` result set, should I additionally call `.ToList()`, or can I just return the `IEnumerable<>` returned by the materialized query with FromCache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using a derivative of the code from http://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/caching-the-results-of-linq-queries/ .  If you look at the `FromCache` implementation, you will see the that the `query.ToList()` is already called.  This means that the evaluated list is what is cached.  So,

You do NOT need to call `ToList()`

Comment: Yes, I'm using that `.FromCache` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

That depends entirely on what you want to do with it.  If you're just going to `foreach` over it once then you may as well just leave it as an `IEnumerable`.  There's no need to build up a list just to discard it right away.

If you plan to iterate over it multiple times it's probably best to `ToList` it, so that you're not accessing the underlying `IQueryable` multiple times.  You should also `ToList` it if it's possible for the underlying query to change over time and you don't want those changes to be reflected in your query.

If you are likely to not need to iterate all of the items (you may end up stopping after the first item, or half way, or something like that) then it's probably best to leave it as an `IEnumerable` to potentially avoid even fetching some amount of data in the first place.

If the method has no idea how it's going to be used, and it's just a helper method that will be used by not-yet-written code, then consider returning `IEnumerable`.  The caller can call `ToList` on it if they have a compelling reason to turn it into a list.

For me, as a general rule, I leave such queries as `IEnumerable` unless I have some compelling reason to make it a `List`.